# How to add comma between day and year JavaScript code using new Date?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that shows the date as "Mar 25 2022" for example. How can modify the code to display a comma between the day number and year? Like this: "Mar 25, 2022"

```
var d = (new Date()).toString().split(' ').splice(1,3).join(' ');
document.write(d)
```

Comment: Is there a specific language using this date structure?

Comment: Ref :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: javascript has its own function to format dates according to languages and countries. Standards and practices must be respected, in order to avoid any ambiguity of interpretation

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show us the code which is generating this date, and if possible you should fix the format mask there to get the output you want.  Assuming you *can't* do that, here is one terse way of adding the comma:

```js
var date = "Mar 25 2022";
date = date.replace(/(?<=\d) /, ", ");
console.log(date);
```